# How to retrieve POSTED content which is larger than limited size in Erlang Cowboy

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I am having a problem in retrieving POST content which is over the limited size (64K) with cowboy_req:body_qs(Req) as it will return {badlength, Data, Req1}

But the data is available if I use cowboy_req:body(Req) with the following format:

param1=value1&parm2=value2...

Here is the way to retrieve data smaller than limited size (64K default)

```
{Post, Req2} = case cowboy_req:body_qs(Req) of
    {ok, Data, Req1} -> {Data, Req1};
    {badlength, Req1} -> {[], Req1}
end
```

And here is the way to retrieve the large data

```
get_post_large(Req) ->
    case cowbod_req:body(Req) of
        {ok, Data, Req1} -> {Data, Req1};
        {more, Data, Req2} -> get_post_large(Req2)
    end.
```

The problem is, get_post_large return the binary:

```
<<"param1=value1&param2=value2....">>
```

And idea on this problem.

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cowboy_req:body(Req, [{length, 10000000}])